# SWRevealVC navigation from child VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I have inherited a project that uses SWReveal(which I have not used before). I am dealing with an issue where I go through a navigation flow from the topVC. i.e.

```
rearVC(this is the slide out menu) -> topVC -> newVC1 -> newVC2 -> newVC3
```

The issue is that on all the newVC's I need the back button to point to the proceeding VC, but from newVC3 I also have a button that needs to slide out the rearVC(menu). This flow has not been implemented before in the project and I am not seeing an easy way to do this.

Edit: I have tried the

```
reavealViewController().toggle
```

call to no avail.

Also, because of the current implementations I am not using a UINavigationController for the newVC flow. Just implementing the navBar on it's own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the difficulty you're facing? Is it what code to write to slide out the navBar in newVC3?

Comment: Exactly. The revealViewController().revealToggle call doesn't work.

Comment: If I’m not wrong your topVC is the only one connected with revealViewController() I’m not sure but to open the menu I think you have to go back to all your hierarchy. You can try for example to call: `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.revealViewController().revealToggle`